# Gson deserialize JSON different types (ANDROID)

Tags: android, json, gson, deserialization

I'm doing a login. If the data is correct return the following:

```
{
   "a": 1,
   "b":2,
   "c":3
}
```

If the data is incorrect return the following:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "error": {
     .... etc
     }

}
```

How should my model?...  **I'm using GSON.**

My code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//As I can get two types of answers, as would my code?
//Model model = gson.fromJson(my_json, Model.class);
```

Comment: Why don't you put all possible fields into your model and then just check `error` for `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you this way :

```
if(responsecode==200){
   Model model = gson.fromJson(my_json, Model.class);
}
else if (responsecode==error){
   AnotherModel anothermodel = gson.fromJson(my_json, AnotherModel.class);
}
```

Also another way is put all possible response in one `Pojo` class , like SqueezyMo said in comments :

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b":2,
  "c":3,
  "status": false,
  "error": "wrong password"
}
```

Paste above json example to this site : [Json Schema 2 Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
And generate your `Pojo` class